# Pass arguments to another function

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

Here I assign one Argument to the Handler:

```
const unsigned argc = 1;
v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[1] = { NanNew("hello world") };

NanMakeCallback(NanGetCurrentContext()->Global(), callHandle, argc, argv);
```

**It works**

But I want to assign two parameters!  **That is why I tried to do:**

```
 const unsigned argc = 2;
 v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[1] = { NanNew("hello world") };
 argv[2] = { NanNew("second argument") };

 NanMakeCallback(NanGetCurrentContext()->Global(), callbackHandle, argc, argv);
```

**But then I get this error:**

```
functions.cc:97:18: error: expected expression
  argv[2] << { NanNew("second argument") };
             ^
```

**What do I wrong? How can I assign two Arguments? Thanks**

Comment: Your error message doesn't match the code snippet you are showing.

Comment: @T.C. Sorry already correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be creating an array of size 1:

```
v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[1] = { NanNew("hello world") };
```

Then trying to assign `{ NanNew("second argument") };` to its element with index 2. This won't work. Did you mean something like this:

```
v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[2] = { NanNew("hello world"), NanNew("second arg") };
```

?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to do initialization in two steps.

```
int values[2] = { 0, 1 }; // OK: Array of two ints initialized with 0 and 1 respectively

int values[2] = { 0 }; // OK: Array of two ints, first value initialized with 0
values[1]= { 1 }; // Error: This is not an initialization
```

The { } syntax is used only for initialization of arrays. (And of course function bodies and such)

In your case, you probably want to do this

```
v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[2] = { NanNew("hello world") , NanNew("second argument") };
```

Note that you previously were trying to create an array with only 1 element, argv[1] and were trying to access the third element, argv[2] = ...

Indexes begin from 0, so valid indexes range from 0 to N-1.